# Best approach to create a global search field for a postgres table in Django based GraphQL API?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I am working with an Angular UI with a Django-graphene GraphQL API and a postgres db.

Currently I have implemented a functionality to arrive at a global search field by adding a "searchField" for each table and updating it with each create and update of an item in that table. And using the graphql filter, every time a user would do a global search, I would just filter hte searchField for the query. I am very new to Django so I'm not sure if this is an efficient way to go about this, but this is what I have:-

Create mutation

```
class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        input = UserInput(required=True)

    ok = graphene.Boolean()
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, input=None):
        ok = True
        searchField = input.username if input.username is not None else "" + \
            input.title if input.title is not None else "" + \
            input.bio if input.bio is not None else ""
        user_instance = User(user_id=input.user_id, title=input.title, bio=input.bio,
                             institution_id=input.institution_id, searchField=searchField)
        user_instance.save()
        return CreateUser(ok=ok, user=user_instance)
```

Update mutation

```
class UpdateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.Int(required=True)
        input = UserInput(required=True)

    ok = graphene.Boolean()
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, id, input=None):
        ok = False
        user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
        user_instance = user
        if user_instance:
            ok = True
            user_instance.name = input.name if input.name is not None else user.name
            user_instance.avatar = input.avatar if input.avatar is not None else user.avatar
            user_instance.institution_id = input.institution_id if input.institution_id is not None else user.institution_id
            user_instance.title = input.title if input.title is not None else user.title
            user_instance.bio = input.bio if input.bio is not None else user.bio
            user_instance.searchField = user_instance.searchField + \
                user_instance.name if user_instance.name is not None else ""
            user_instance.searchField = user_instance.searchField + \
                user_instance.title if user_instance.title is not None else ""
            user_instance.searchField = user_instance.searchField + \
                user_instance.bio if user_instance.bio is not None else ""
            user_instance.save()
            return UpdateUser(ok=ok, user=user_instance)
        return UpdateUser(ok=ok, user=None)
```

Not sure if you can tell, but I'm very new to Python and Django. And what I'm doing here is, every time a user record is created or updated, I am maintaining a field in the table called `searchField` that will have a string of all the fields in the table that I want the global search to touch upon. I've manually written each line like that. Not sure if this is in line with best practice.

Here's the user model.

User model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, max_length=255, unique=True)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    institution = models.ForeignKey(
        'Institution', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    searchField = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True, null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
```

So there are a couple of things here.

1. First I know that I'm doing something wrong in terms of setting up the updating of the searchField in the update mutation resolver method. That's due to my poor knowledge of Python. So if someone could sort out what I'm doing wrong that would be great.
2. I am doing this completely on my own, I have no idea if this approach is actually a good strategy in terms of efficiency or if there's already a good solution for graphql based django api. So if there is please point me to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to update your searchField you have to build it from scratch. If you use old data and append new data, it will return the record if you search for old data and that's something you want to avoid.

Regarding your second question, you can use `django-filter`.

Steps:

1. install `django-filter`
2. create a base filterset class and add `search` field to it

   ```
   class CustomFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
       search = filters.CharFilter(method='search_filter')

       def search_filter(self, queryset, field_name, value):
           return queryset
   ```
3. create filterset class for your models inheriting from your custom filterset class and override `search_filter` method. In order to perform `or` operations on querysets use `Q` object. In your case something like:

   ```
   class UserFilterSet(CustomFilterSet):
       ...
       def search_filter(self, queryset, field_name, value):
           return queryset.filter(
               Q(username__icontains=value) |
               Q(title__icontains=vallue) |
               Q(bio__icontains=value)
           )
   ```

   which looks for the value in specified fields regardless of
   being lower/upper case
4. create graphql types and add related filterset_class to Meta class:

   ```
   class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
       class Meta:
           model = User
           filterset_class = UserFilterSet
           interfaces = (relay.Node, )
   ```

Now you can search globally for the specified fields by passing just a single string.